# nginx: Redirection from old to new git base URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, git

I would like to redirect the old base url of git repositories. I use the following code:

```
location ~ ^/scm/git/(.*) {
    return 301 /scm/repo/git/$1;
}
```

In the browser, the redirection works fine, but when I try to clone the repository, I get the following error message:

```
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
asked for: https://example.com/scm/git/xxxx/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
redirect: https://example.com/scm/repo/git/xxxx/info/refs
```

Can you please help me, what have I forgotten? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In `location`, nginx uses only normalised URI, which doesn't include query arguments.

You need to use the following to include query arguments:

```
location ~ ^/scm/git/(.*) {
    return 301 /scm/repo/git/$1$is_args$args;
}
```